# nodeJs - post request with form-data using Unirest

Tags: node.js, post, postman, multipartform-data, unirest

[image: postman request]

how can I post a file(please refer my screenshot) with unirest in node.js. I have gone through unirest [doc](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html)
it's found that can use the below code for sending form-data to a given URL

```
unirest.post('http://mockbin.com/request')
.headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
 .field('parameter', 'value') // Form field
.attach('file', '/tmp/file') // Attachment
.end(function (response) {
 console.log(response.body);
});
```

please have a look at the screenshot attached. needed to give the key name as 'html'.

how to export the same postman request to node.js(unirest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `.attach('file', '/tmp/file')`, first argument is field name(key name according to you) and second is file path, you can pass as following

```
var unirest = require('unirest');

unirest.post('http://localhost:3000/api/addProject/')
.headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
.attach('html', 'D:\\data\\index.html') // Attachment
.end(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Comment: '.field('parameter', 'value') // Form field'


why are we adding this to our code?

Comment: you may remove if not required, that is only example to pass data with file, you can remove that line

Comment: the issue is fixed. I was trying to send the file itself on the .attach section. worked when I have given the s3 URL of the same file